# How to test set method on nsubstitute mock

Tags: unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nunit, nsubstitute

I am completely re-writing this now that I am sitting in front of my project. I am still having issue with understanding how to write the test correctly.

Here is the class I am trying to test:

```
namespace Snowball.Controllers
{
    public class FollowCameraController : ICameraController
    {
        private ITransform player;
        private ITransform camera;
        private IVector3Utility utility;
        private IVector3 offset;

        public FollowCameraController(ITransform player, ITransform camera, IVector3Utility utility)
        {
            this.player = player;
            this.camera = camera;
            this.utility = utility;

            offset = utility.Subtract(camera.Position, player.Position);
        }

        public void UpdateCameraPosition()
        {
            IVector3 playerPosition = player.Position;

            IVector3 newCameraPosition = utility.Add(playerPosition, offset);

            camera.Position = newCameraPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test suite that I am running and it is the only test in the suite right now that I am trying to test:

```
namespace FrameworkTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class FollowCameraControllerTest
    {
        private ITransform cameraTransformMock;
        private ITransform playerTransformMock;
        private IVector3Utility utilityMock;

        private IVector3 offset;

        private FollowCameraController sut;

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            cameraTransformMock = Substitute.For<ITransform>();
            playerTransformMock = Substitute.For<ITransform>();
            utilityMock = Substitute.For<IVector3Utility>();

            offset = Substitute.For<IVector3>();

            utilityMock.Subtract(Arg.Any<IVector3>(), Arg.Any<IVector3>()).Returns(offset);

            sut = new FollowCameraController(cameraTransformMock, playerTransformMock, utilityMock);

            var temp = utilityMock.Received().Subtract(Arg.Any<IVector3>(), Arg.Any<IVector3>());
        }

        [Test]
        public void WhenUpdateCameraIsCalledThenCameraPositionIsUpdated()
        {
            //var playerPosition = Substitute.For<IVector3>();
            var cameraPosition = Substitute.For<IVector3>();

            var playerPosition = playerTransformMock.Position;

            utilityMock.Add(playerPosition, offset).Returns(cameraPosition);

            //var temp = cameraTransformMock.Position;
            //cameraTransformMock.Position = cameraPosition;

            sut.UpdateCameraPosition();

            var temp = playerTransformMock.Received().Position;
            temp = utilityMock.Received().Add(playerPosition, offset);
            //cameraTransformMock.Received().Position = cameraPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

This test fails with the following failed test output:

Result Message: 
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException : Expected to receive a call matching:

Add(IVector3Proxy, IVector3Proxy)
Actually received no matching calls.
Received 1 non-matching call (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):
    Add(*IVector3Proxy*, IVector3Proxy)

I am hoping someone can point out what I have done wrong or how I am misusing NSubstitute. I am lost on how to test this method

Comment: I think I might have found out what I was doing wrong and it was at the VectorAdapter level where I am using the get/set methods. I will update if I experience anymore problems. Essentially I was creating a new IVector3 inside of every get method instead of just updating an exisiting IVector3, looked good through unity but is completely untestable or so it would appear

Comment: Still not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FollowCameraController` constructor takes `player` then `camera`:

```
public FollowCameraController(ITransform player, ITransform camera, IVector3Utility utility) { ... }
```

But your test instantiates the `sut` with `camera` then `player`:

```
sut = new FollowCameraController(cameraTransformMock, playerTransformMock, utilityMock);
```

I think that is a large part of the problem. :)

As an aside, `UpdateCameraPosition` updates the camera position using the player position and the `IVector3Utility` instance, so I would make that the focus of the test:

```
    [Test]
    public void WhenUpdateCameraIsCalledThenCameraPositionIsUpdated()
    {
        var newCameraPosition = Substitute.For<IVector3>();
        var playerPosition = playerTransformMock.Position;
        utilityMock.Add(playerPosition, offset).Returns(newCameraPosition);

        sut.UpdateCameraPosition();

        Assert.AreSame(cameraTransformMock.Position, newCameraPosition);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the fact that I had flip flopped the two parameters and didn't even notice it :(. Thank you very much for pointing that out, I totally whiffed on that! Now my test is passing and I absolutely agree all I wanted to test was the fact that the camera position was the same as the newCameraPosition.